# Google Earth Engine exported tif file is unprojected (or strange coordinate system?)

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

Just starting to learn Google Earth Engine. Sorry if this is covered elsewhere but I couldn't find a tutorial or post about it.

I'm doing a pretty simple image export, but when I load the TIFF into QGIS later (to add state boundaries, etc) it seems to have an incorrect coordinate system and doesn't match up with other shapefiles.

Here's the code:

```
var cdl = ee.Image('USDA/NASS/CDL/2017').select('cropland')

var crops = ee.List([1,4,5,7,9,10, 31, 33, 36, 45, 63, 64, 86, 241])

var mask = ee.Image(cdl)
  .eq(1)
var masked = ee.Image(cdl)
  .updateMask(cdl.eq(1))

// Map.addLayer(filtered)
Map.addLayer(mask, {}, 'mask')
Map.addLayer(masked, {}, 'masked')

var remapped = cdl.remap({
  from: crops,
  to: ee.List.repeat(1, crops.size()),
  defaultValue: 0
})

Map.addLayer(remapped, {}, 'remapped')

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: masked,
  description: 'corn-test',
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 99999999
});
```

It's worked with another dataset so not sure why this one is off.

Here's a screenshot of what the tif looks like in QGIS next to an actual shapefile from the Census:

[image: layers don't match]

CRS for the corn tif:

```
USER:100025 - * Generated CRS (+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs) - Projected
```

CRS for the census shapefile:

```
EPSG:4269 - NAD83 - Geographic
```

I've tried to re-project the tif and it always seems to disappear (nothing happens when I "zoom to layer")

Comment: Are you sure your census shapefile has been assigned the correct CRS? I.e. are you sure the GEE geotiff is improperly located, or could it be the census one? You can check the CRS by double-clicking the layer in QGIS and looking at the "Information" tab. Make sure the CRS matches what the data provider says it should. (And you should report that information in your question.)

Comment: edited the original post above with CRS information

Comment: Using QGIS, you can add a base layer like OpenStreetMap from the QMS plugin to see which dataset is correct and which is misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set the CRS of the export image by using the `crs` argument. That should theoretically solve the problem.

```
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: masked,
  description: 'corn-test',
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 99999999,
  crs: 'epsg:4326',
});
```